# I'm receiving sqlite operational error when running prefect workflow

Tags: prefect

```
import time
from prefect import task, flow

@task
def my_task():
    return 1

@flow
def my_flow():
    my_task.submit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_flow()
```

I'm trying run this simple flow but I always get this error below. I'm using prefect==2.2.0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your DB migration didn't work correctly. There are a couple of things you could do to resolve that:

1. Set `prefect config set PREFECT_ORION_DATABASE_MIGRATE_ON_START='False'` if you want to avoid Orion running migration on startup
2. Reset your DB: `prefect orion database reset -y`
3. Remove your SQLite DB file `rm ~/.prefect/orion.db` and then start Orion again